# Business Event framework

Tags: java, events, listeners

I am building a social networking kind of site. I am looking for a
highly scalable free and open source framework for event processing.

e.g when a user does some action on website, it would trigger an
event of a particular type for backend. A number of listeners will be waiting 
for this type of event and as soon as those listen to event, they would do
some application logic for that event e.g. sending emails/sms, or data mining or start a bulb
.. literally anything.

Does anyone know any such framework? Let me know if I am not clear enough.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Axon framework](http://code.google.com/p/axonframework/).

> Axon Framework helps build scalable, extensible and maintainable
>   applications by supporting developers apply the Command Query
>   Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) architectural pattern. It does so by
>   providing implementations of the most important building blocks, such
>   as aggregates, repositories and event buses (the dispatching mechanism
>   for events). Furthermore, Axon provides annotation support, which
>   allows you to build aggregates and event listeners withouth tying your
>   code to Axon specific logic. This allows you to focus on your business
>   logic, instead of the plumbing, and helps you to make your code easier
>   to test in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

[JMS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) provides this. Send a message to a topic, and all the listeners on that topic will receive the message.

There are several free implementations available (ActiveMQ, JBoss Messaging, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) is interesting for you, e.g. it offers [distributed listeners and events](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#Events) among other interesting features for distributed applications like distributed maps, locks, distributed topic for publish/subscribe messaging etc.

> Hazelcast allows you to register for entry events to get notified when entries added, updated or removed. Listeners are cluster-wide. When a member adds a listener, it is actually registering for events originated in any member in the cluster. When a new member joins, events originated at the new member will also be delivered.